# What is the process of going from Dubai Airport to Abu Dhabi?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, dubai, abu-dhabi

I am travelling to Abu Dhabi for a job but I have never been outside my country. My questions are:

- How hard is it to reach departure location from Dubai airport to Abu Dhabi airport? I saw in youtube videos that you even need to take a train to reach terminal. Also are all the three terminals in Dubai require train travel?
- Where will I be able to take my belongings when I port from Dubai to Abu Dhabi?
- Finally if I get lost whom should I ask?

Comment: How area you planning to get between the two locations?  Taxi? Uber? Bus? Walking?

Comment: @Doc through airplane. From Dubai To Abu Dhabi

Comment: @Subik There are no flights between the two, since they are only around 140 km apart.  You will need to use ground transport.

Comment: It’s unclear to me what you are asking about. Where are you leaving from and where are you going to? Do you already have flights booked? Note that Abu Dhabi and Dubai are two different cities, and each has its own airport. They’re not very far from one another but it’s not next door either, so if your goal is Abu Dhabi it could make more sense to take a flight to Abu Dhabi rather than fly to Dubai and then have to travel by road.

Comment: They are two completely different airports - chances are a taxi would probably be easiest and fastest (and to be honest, not very expensive - I always found them cheap in the UAE). Or, could you just not fly into the airport you're wanting?